# How to adjust the width of react flexbox grid items to allow space between them?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-flexbox-grid

The problem I have should be simple enough to solve, but I don't understand flexbox enough to understand what is happening.

I am trying to get two divs side by side with some space between them, but I cannot adjust their widths at all.

The html(jsx) code looks like this:

```
        <Col className="DivA"  xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={3}>
           //stuff
        </Col>

        <Col  className="DivB" xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={9}>
           //stuff
        </Col>
```

And the css:

```
.DivA {
    height: 700px;
    float: left;
    width: flexbox keeps width at 100% of whatever space its allowed
}

.DivB {
    height: 700px;
    float: right;
}
```

I can adjust the margins, but it moves the other div below the first one. I can adjust all the other properties, except the width. I want the divs to have space between them but nothing I have tried works.

I have no idea where this property is coming from and even putting !important in the css does nothing.

Edit: Found a workaround by changing lg={2.5} in DivA and adding a margin-left in DivB, but i am still wondering if there is a better way..

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `float` together with `flex`. It's useless. Better yet, do not use `float` at all when it comes to layout.

You can use `flex` on the container together with `justify-content: space-between`.

for example purposes i added `width: calc(50% - 20px)` which means that there will be 40px space between them.

See below

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  height:50px;
  background: red;
  width:calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a item">
  </div>
  <div class="b item">
  </div>
</div>
```